# Prevent an AppleScript script from changing its own modification date when using passed arguments

Tags: applescript, osx-lion

I have an AppleScript script that I use to display iTunes track information on my desktop with GeekTool. I use `on runargv` to pass different parameters to the script so I can show different parts of the track information without duplicating the script (for example, I can get just the title by running `osascript itunes.scpt title` and I can get the artist/album by running `osascript itunes.scpt album`).

However, every time I run the script with an argument, the actual file modification date is changed—it seems that the script is writing *something* to itself or making some sort of modification.

This isn't ordinarily a problem, except in OS X 10.7, where Lion introduced file locking for files that haven't been modified in more than 2 weeks. Once my iTunes script is locked by the OS, it can't make any more of these invisible self updates when it runs, and my system log gets riddled with errors like this:

```
osascript: couldn't save changes to script /path/to/script: error -54
```

I can fix this temporarily by making some modification to the script manually (adding empty lines, for example), but two weeks later it all breaks down again because Lion locks it.

I could theoretically disable file locking systemwide to fix this, but I'd rather not—I like it for other things.

So, how can you use `on run argv` to pass arguments to AppleScript files *without* changing the modification date of that script?

Here's a minimal working example. If you run this from the command line (`oscascript test.scpt blah`), the script's modification date will change.

```
--test.scpt
on run argv
    tell application "iTunes"
        if player state is playing then
            set trck to current track
            set title_text to (get name of trck)
            return title_text & " " & item 1 of argv
        end if
    end tell
end run
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to properties that are defined in a regular AppleScript (not the Xcode variety), *all* global variables are persistent and are saved with a script (at least until it is recompiled).  This includes items defined in the **run** handler (either explicit or implied), for example:

```
on run
    try
        display dialog someVariable -- will error the first time
    on error -- set global
        beep
        set someVariable to time string of (current date)
    end try
end run
```

You might try moving your code to a handler so that global variables are not set or changed.

Comment: Which variables are persistent and global in this case then? Anything that goes in the `run` handler, or the things that are getting set in the iTunes procedure? Would I just move all the iTunes stuff to a separate handler and just call it from inside `run`?

Comment: All of the variables defined in the run handler such as trck and title_text would be global.  Moving the whole thing to a separate handler and calling that from the run handler should do it, since those variables would then be local and not saved with the script.

Comment: Wow, I never knew this. Thanks for demonstrating this. I was able to fix the issue without putting the code in a separate handler. Just add "local someVariable" at the top inside the run handler. When you do this the "display dialog" is never shown and the modification date of the script never changes.

Comment: Awesome. Moving everything to a new handler worked perfectly. Is `run` the only handler that makes everything global like this, or are there other built-in handlers that can cause this problem?

Comment: I haven't tested all of the other predefined handlers (the open handler does work as expected - variables are local unless otherwise declared), but I am guessing that the run handler is a special case since it doesn't have to be explicitly declared.

Answer (score 1):

You can try feeding the script to `osascript` via stdin instead of reading it directly.

```
osascript - args < /path/to/script
```

or

```
cat /path/to/script | osascript - args
```

You need the dash in there (see the manpage for `osascript`)

However, I can't reproduce the modification-time-updated behavior (I'm on Snow Leopard), so I don't know if this will be any different. But it might work since `osascript` isn't in direct contact with the file (if indeed it's `osascript`'s fault).

Strange issue in any case

Comment: Hrm. Both of those options give me this error: `0:13: syntax error: A real number can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)`. But it's also giving me the same error if I try using that syntax on the super simple example `a.scpt` in the `osascript` manpage.

Comment: @Andrew Weird. I tested both the commands before posting, and they worked just fine on Snow Leopard... but then so does your original command.

Comment: @Andrew: A `.scpt` file is not just a script, it contains the script code in text form but also the script in pre-compiled form and everything together is stored in a binary format. If you tell `osascript` to read a script file, it knows how to extract the pure script from the `.scpt` file, but when fed data via `STDIN`, it expect pure script code (ASCII) and not the content of a script file. Scripts stored as pure text in the ScriptEditor don't have the extension `.scpt` but `.applescript` and are just human readable script source.

Comment: @Andrew Try this `osadecompile a.scpt | osascript - Andrew`

Comment: @Mecki Thank you for this, that worked for me! I didn't know about `osadecompile`